# Problem with searching the report with openargs in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form  in MS Access where on button click event I have the following code running. My objective is to make a user enter a value on button click on a form and send that value to report using openargs. I wanted to add the openargs parameter in that query but when I enter a value on the inputbox and hit enter I get a prompt called "Enter Parameter" which asks me to enter value for all the fields in the report. I am new to VBA and don't know what I am doing wrong

**Form**

```
strInput = InputBox("Which value did you want to print?")
    DoCmd.OpenReport "01-REPORT", acPreview, , , , OpenArgs = strInput
```

**Report**

In my report on open report event I have

```
 Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.OpenArgs > 0 Then
    Me.RecordSource = "PRINT FINAL DATA WHERE " & "InvNum = '" & Me.OpenArgs & "'"
    End If
End Sub
```

*PRINT FINAL DATA * is the name of a query which is the recordsource of the report.

Answer (score 0):

To open report with filtered data you can do this:

1. In Design view for report's `RecordSource` set query with all data
   (your `*PRINT FINAL DATA *`). And save it.
2. For form in click handler write this (i omit all error check & etc)

   `strInput = InputBox("Which value did you want to print?")
   DoCmd.OpenReport "01-REPORT", acPreview, , "InvNum = '" & strInput & "'"`

The forth parameter of `OpenReport` is `WhereCondition` which filters data before doing report.

P.S. And report asks for value of every field because your report don't have saved value in `RecordSource` when you open it. Or query have no such fields.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that DoCmd.OpenReport had option to add where condition. But follwong your code gives me this error on the openreport line with the where condidiotn

Comment: "this expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be evaluated"

Comment: 1. check if report works when opened manually 2. check if  `InvNum` is text type in query/table 3. check what is `WhereCondition` is not wrong.